# Lines counted raw or nonblank noncomment

Tags: statistics, metrics, code-metrics, line-count

When the size of a code base is reported in lines, is it more usual/standard to report raw `wc` count, or nonblank noncomment lines? I'm not asking which measure *should* be used, only, if I see a number given with no other information, which measure it is at best guess more likely to be.

Comment: It depends... how honest are you? :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say nonblank, noncomment lines.  For many languages in the C family tree, this is approximately the number of semi-colons.